# Proper permissions for postfix piped script

Tags: linux, permissions, php, postfix, pipe

As my almost-alliterative title states, I am attempting to configure postfix to pipe incoming messages to a PHP script.  As it currently stands, postfix apparently attempts to run the script as the 'nobody' user, which means that if the script is located anywhere other than a public directory with o+r access, I get a permission denied error when postfix tries to run the script.

How should I configure permissions? Should postfix be configured to run the script as a different user? or should I just create a public directory and grant o+r permissions to this directory and the script so that the 'nobody' user can access it?

What's the best practice solution?

Thanks!